# How to add two times in PHP

Tags: php

I need to add two times and want to get total hours.

Here is my code:

```
foreach($result_data as $res) {

    if( !empty($res['in1']) && !empty($res['out1']) ) {

        $in1 = new DateTime($res['in1']);
        $out1 = new DateTime($res['out1']);
        $interval1 = $in1->diff($out1);
        $h1 = $interval1->format('%H') . ":" . $interval1->format('%I');

        $h2 = $h3 = "00:00";

        if( !empty($res['in2']) && !empty($res['out2']) ) {

            $in2 = new DateTime($res['in2']);
            $out2 = new DateTime($res['out2']);
            $interval2 = $in2->diff($out2);
            $h2 = $interval2->format('%H') . ":" . $interval2->format('%I');

            if( !empty($res['in3']) && !empty($res['out3']) ) {

                $in3 = new DateTime($res['in3']);
                $out3 = new DateTime($res['out3']);
                $interval3 = $in2->diff($out3);
                $h3 = $interval3->format('%H') . ":" . $interval3->format('%I');
            }

        }

        $hours = strtotime($h1) + strtotime($h2) + strtotime($h3);
        $res['total_hours'] = date("H:I", $hours);      
        $res_data[] = $res;

    }
}
```

The error am getting is

> date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given in

Can anyone please help me to find out the issue? Why `$hours` is float value?

Comment: Try this : `date("H:I", intval($hours));` but maybe careful if the string begin with `0`, intval can remove it

Comment: It's not working. Getting 00:00 output

Comment: Whats the value of all `$res` var ? An example of what you can get

Comment: I have updated my code in answer and `$result_data` is array which contains value for `in1, out1, in2, out2, in3, out3` @Jean-maximeBouloc

Comment: After using `intval()` am also not getting error but also not getting correct output @PatrickQ

Comment: Don't have error too. Can you give the value of `$res['in1']`, `$res['in2']`, `$res['out1']` and `$res['out2']` when it show you this error

Comment: ya it's `$res['in1'] = :10:07 & $res['out1'] = 14:48`  and `$res['in2'] = :15:44 & $res['out2'] = 20:00`